# I have a problem booting Ubuntu 9

Tags: dual-boot

I have installed Ubuntu 9 on an Asus motherboard,I 3, from a disc;
it is installed along with Windows.

Now I have 2 problems:

a) I cannot boot into Linux without changing the sata setting in the bios to anci
 and I have no internet connectivity also in Ubuntu mode.

b) To boot into Linux I have to change the bios sata setting back to ide and boot to Windows; then my internet connection works fine.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please remove your Ubuntu partition, recover your Ubuntu bootloader and install Ubuntu 12.04.

Ubuntu 9.x is "ancient" and not supported anymore.

Comment: Store any data you want to keep externally though so you dont lose it.

Answer (score 5):

## Ubuntu 9.04 and 9.10 are both past end of life.

This means they are not supported.  **It is highly inadvisable to install them** (if not already installed), **and is even more inadvisable to continue to use them** because of the lack of updates and security patches.  Use **10.04** or **12.04** if you want stability (12.04 is the most recent release and will contain updated packages).  The updated versions of Ubuntu (10.04, 12.04) may actually have a fix for these issues.